# Java Wav file Error (javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file)

Tags: java, events, audio, javasound

I have two Classes in my Java Project one is

Rebound

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rebound
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Rebound");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.getContentPane().add(new ReboundPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

and the second one is ReboundPanel

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

public class ReboundPanel extends JPanel
{
   private final int WIDTH = 600, HEIGHT = 300;
   private final int DELAY = 20, IMAGE_SIZE = 35;

   private ImageIcon image1, image2, image3;
   private Timer timer;
   private int x1, y1, moveX1, moveY1, x2, y2, moveX2, moveY2, x3, y3;
   Clip clip;
   DataLine.Info info;

   public ReboundPanel() throws Exception
   {
      timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ReboundListener());
      image1 = new ImageIcon ("happyFace1.gif");
      image2 = new ImageIcon ("happyFace2.gif");


      x1 = 0;
      y1 = 100;
      x2 = 40;
      y2 = 0;
      moveX1 = moveY1 = 3;
      moveX2 = moveY2 = 5;
      setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
      setBackground (Color.black);
      timer.start();

      image3 = new ImageIcon ("fire.gif");
      File soundFile = new File("explosion.wav");
      AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
      DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info (Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
      clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
      clip.open(sound);
      clip.start();
   }
   public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
   {
      super.paintComponent (page);
      image1.paintIcon (this, page, x1, y1);
      image2.paintIcon (this, page, x2, y2);
      image3.paintIcon (this, page, x2, y2);
   }
   private class ReboundListener implements ActionListener
   {

      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {
         x1 += moveX1;
         y1 += moveY1;
         x2 += moveX2;
         y2 += moveY2;
         if (x1 <= 0 || x1 >= WIDTH-IMAGE_SIZE)
            moveX1 = moveX1 * -1;

         if (y1 <= 0 || y1 >= HEIGHT-IMAGE_SIZE)
            moveY1 = moveY1 * -1;

         if (x2 <= 0 || x2 >= WIDTH-IMAGE_SIZE)
            moveX2 = moveX2 * -1;

         if (y2 <= 0 || y2 >= HEIGHT-IMAGE_SIZE)
            moveY2 = moveY2 * -1;

         if (Math.abs(y1-y2) <= IMAGE_SIZE-2 && Math.abs(x1-x2)<= IMAGE_SIZE-2)
            {
                moveY2 = moveY2 * -1;
                moveX2 = moveX2 * -1;
                moveY1 = moveY1 * -1;
                moveX1 = moveX1 * -1;
                x3=x2;
                y3=y2-2*IMAGE_SIZE;
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

            }
         if (Math.abs(y1-y2) >= 4*IMAGE_SIZE && Math.abs(x1-x2) >= 4*IMAGE_SIZE)
           {
               x3=-200;
               y3=-200;
               if (clip.isRunning()) clip.stop();
           }
         repaint();
      }
   }
}
```

When I try to run the program I get the following error

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1187)
    at ReboundPanel.<init>(ReboundPanel.java:47)
    at Rebound.main(Rebound.java:21)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ReboundPanel$ReboundListener.actionPerformed(ReboundPanel.java:99)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:312)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:244)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

According to my Code my goal is to make two happy faces move in the frame and when they both collide a sound along with an image of fire/explosion should show up and disappear

Please help I have to show this project to my instructor...

Comment: Does `explosion.wav` actually exist in the directory you're running the code from? Is it a valid `wav` file?

Comment: A simple search got me this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104118/javax-sound-sampled-unsupportedaudiofileexception-could-not-get-audio-input-str

Comment: yes it does exist in the directory

Answer (score 8):

Just because a file is a WAV doesn't mean it is supported by JavaSound. A WAV file is a container format, and the actual raw data (the samples) may be in different formats, including signed/unsigned PCM at a variety of bit depths or it may be in a compressed format. I can't find the compatibility table for JavaSound, but the compatibility table for JMF (which will give you a good idea) is here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html

The solution is to convert the WAV file to a more generic format, like 16-bit PCM using a conversion program that can read your current file (SoX, Adacity, QuickTime, ProTools, etc).

To be more precise, you may want to create a WAV file with a bit depth of 16-bits (little endian -- this is the default, so if you don't see it don't worry), stereo or mono should work. You may also want to consider common sample rates such as 44,100 Hz, or 48,000 Hz (most computers nowadays should support both rates, but the former is somewhat more common).

Comment: Expanding a bit on the answer: the format 16-bit PCM, little endian, 44100 fps, stereo is often used by javax.sound.sampled.Clip and SourceDataLine. Audacity is free. If your .wav files are not in the above format, you can use Audacity to convert them. (Fairly easy to do.) Some conversions can be done within Java as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html but this is perhaps a more difficult approach with run time downsides if you are implementing it on the fly.

Comment: answer updated. Note, though, that you can't use Java for the conversions, since java can't read the files in the first place, it won't be able to convert them.

Comment: *"I can't find the compatibility table for JavaSound"*  Since it works by SPI, it is best to get the information from the J2SE at run-time.  See the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for more details on SPI and the Java Sound Capabilities (obtained via `AudioSystem`).

Comment: True, but there are built-in, default capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

> An `UnsupportedAudioFileException` is an exception indicating that an operation failed because a file did not contain valid data of a recognized file type and format.

If the question were "Why don't the samples play?" the answer would be above.  Another way to put it is "The sound uses a format or encoding that the Java Sound API does not understand".

..What is your question?