# Java - Unsupported Audio File Exception

Tags: java, swing, audio, audio-streaming

I'm trying to add sound to my java game...

I'm playing Sultans of swing at runtime:

```
static String WHOOSH = "res/WHOOSH.WAV";
static String SULTANS = "res/DireStraits_SultansOfSwing.wav";
```

`music(SULTANS, true);`

And this whoosh sound when the ball hits a paddle

`music(WHOOSH, false);`

```
public void music(String path, Boolean loop) {
    try {
        //will go into file folder and get music file (getResource)
        AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(GamePanel.class.getResource(path));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        clip.start();
        if (loop) {
            clip.loop(1000);
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Check: " + path + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

The "Whoosh" always works, but Sultans of Swing does not. Sultans gives me this "Unsupported Audio File Exception" error, which oracle docs tells me

`An UnsupportedAudioFileException is an exception indicating that an operation failed because a file did not contain valid data of a recognized file type and format.`

**Error:**

```
Check: res/DireStraits_SultansOfSwing.wav

javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

But you can see from these photos that they're both .wav files...

[image]

[image]

Why is it throwing that error? Is it a size issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suspect that the either the internal encoding of the file is unsupported or the file is corrupt. +1 for Sultans ;)

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104118/javax-sound-sampled-unsupportedaudiofileexception-could-not-get-audio-input-str

Answer (score -1):

When I've used wav files for a game, I've done something like this (I've updated it with your path):

```
    public void endingSound() throws IOException{

        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream failSound = cl.getResourceAsStream("res/DireStraits_SultansOfSwing.wav");

        if (failSound != null){

            AudioStream as = new AudioStream(failSound);         
            AudioPlayer.player.start(as);  
        }
        else{

            System.err.println("cannot load ending sound");
        }   

}
```

In this way I assure you won't have any problems when you will export as jar. If is still doesn't work try to rename or replace that file; it may be corrupted as @MadProgrammer said.

Comment: `AudioStream` is from `sun.audio` package which is not standard.